# Why Android in app billing need buy and consume for an item?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

When looking at other mobile OS, like iOS and FirefoxOS, they only have one function(buy) for a consumable item. Once you buy an item, you will get it with a success callback.

But for [Android](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consumetypes), it need two steps:

1. First you call buy() for an item. Then server will record ownership for you, but it is not in your app yet.
2. Call consume() for this item. Then server will remove the ownership and notify you, by that your app gets the item for user.

I can't see why it takes two separate steps for purchasing an consumable item on Android, while other OS only need one step?

Answer (score 0):

I think API has been evolving from earlier versions and currently there is only one type of products. All items are consumable and when you want to consume, you simply call consume(). Before there was different types that made it complex.